# Como sacer una copia de la base de datos si estoy en android studio con base de datos sqlite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, local-storage

Ando haciendo un proyecto donde tengo una base de datos en Sqlite.

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/liferegisterdiary/DatabaseController.java

la base de datos es totalmente funcional CRUD

Ahora bien... yo uso mysql y existe el mysqldump y eso me bota un archivo .sql en donde me quedan los siguientes campos:

```
mysqldump [opciones] nombre_bd [nombre_tabla1 nombre_tabla2 ...] > respaldo.sql
```

//Resultado:

```
INSERT INTO <NombreTabla> values (valor, valor, valor...);
INSERT INTO <NombreTabla> values (valor, valor, valor...);
INSERT INTO <NombreTabla> values (valor, valor, valor...);
```

Existe una forma de hacer esto en sqlite????

Comment: La copia la deseas realizar programaticamente? Como deseas realizar la copia? agrega más información, si deseas un opinión como realizarlo, recuerda revisar [ask], hay que agregar lo que se investigo o trato, de otra forma puedes preguntar en [chat], saludos.

Comment: Hola... No.
Si conoces mysql existe mysqldump que te entrega un archivo plano con un backup de la base de datos... Osea con un solo comando te da toda la información de la base de datos dividida en sentencias SQL inser into...
Estoy preguntando si existe lo mismo para sqlite.

Comment: Creo que ha habido una discusión igual en cuanto a este problema, mira si este link te ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250468/copy-database-from-assets-folder

Answer (score 0):

1 -> se debe de obtener el nombre todas las tablas en una lista String

```
/****
     * return all tables of database
     *
     * @return {"t_name, t_name, t_name..."}
     */
    public List<String> getAllTableNames(){
        List<String> tablesNames = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            //Create a consult to extract table names
            DatabaseController databaseController = new DatabaseController(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = databaseController.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                while (!c.isAfterLast()){
                    String tableName = c.getString(0);
                    tablesNames.add(tableName);
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            //Do nothing
        }

        return tablesNames;
    }
```

2 -> Por cada Tabla se debe de obtener el nombre de cada columna:

```
            //Get table column names
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO("+"\'"+listOfTables.get(i)+"\')", null);
            List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
            if(c.moveToFirst()){
                while (!c.isAfterLast()){
                    columnNames.add(c.getString(0));
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
            }
```

3 -> Se debe de retornar el tipo de dato con ' ' comillas simples para los strings

```
public List<String> getTableTYPEandData(String tableName){

List<String> info = new ArrayList<>();

try{

    DatabaseController databaseController = new DatabaseController(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = databaseController.getWritableDatabase();

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    //information.add(sql);
    Cursor getValues = db.rawQuery(sql, null);



    while (getValues.moveToNext()) {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<getValues.getColumnCount();i++){


            switch (getValues.getType(i))  {
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                    temp.add(String.valueOf(getValues.getInt(i)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                    temp.add("\'"+getValues.getString(i)+"\'");
                    break;
            }
        }

        info.add(temp.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
    }

    getValues.close();


}catch (Exception e){
    //Do nothing
}


return info;
```

}

Crear los encabezados y anidar

```
tableNames = getAllTableNames();
DATABASEBACKUP = ""; //Aqui se vana  guardar las consultas

for(tableNames){
    String sqlBACKUPHEAD = "INSERT INTO " + listOfTables.get(i) + " (";
    
    String nameCols = columnNames.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "") + ") VALUES (";
    String values = "";
    for(nameOfColunsTable){
       //Pegar Aqui todos los valores
       values = getTableTYPEandData(tableNames.i)+ ");\n";
       //Aqui se hace el Backup
       DATABASEBACKUP = DATABASEBACKUP + sqlBACKUPHEAD + nameCols + values;
    }


}
```

Para ver este ejemplo en vivo y en directo:

https://github.com/felipedelosh/LifeRegisterAPP/blob/main/app/src/main/java/db/PASSWORD.java

Metodo:

backupDatabase()

Ejemplo de salida:

```
INSERT INTO t_profile (username, sex, yearBirthDate, monthBirthDate, dayBirthDate) VALUES ('felipedelosh', 'male', 1991, 1, 13);
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (8, 'Alcohol');
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (9, 'Cannabis');
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (10, 'Cocaína');
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (11, 'Éxtasis');
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (12, 'Juego');
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (13, 'Nicotina');
INSERT INTO t_drugs (ID, drugName) VALUES (14, 'Pornografia');
```